# Unable to prevent an input from submitting when press the enter key on it

Tags: html, get, submit, enter, preventdefault

I'm getting an unexpected behaviour from an input. I have the following code:

```
<form id="search_form">
    <div id="search_container">
       <input type="text" id="search_text">
    </div>
    <select onchange="search_field_on_change()" name="search_field">
       <option value="login" selected>Usuario</option>
       <option value="su.name">Nombre</option>
       <option value="surnames">Apellidos</option>
       <option value="email">Correo</option>
       <option value="role">Rol</option>
       <option value="access">Acceso</option>
       <option value="center">Centro</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button" onclick="search()">Buscar</button>
    <span id="modify_user_message"></span>
</form>
```

When I press the enter key on the input element, the form is submitted and the following request is executed:

```
GET home.php?search_field=login
```

I want to avoid this behaviour. I've tried it with this:

```
$('#search_text').keypress(function(e){
    console.log('Hello');
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which == 13){
        search();
    }
});
```

But I don't get anything in the console, so I think the request is performed before the event can be captured.

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `keypress` event to `keydown` because the default behavior of the Enter key is captured on keydown so you have to prevent it at the point where it starts doing its default action.

Here's a working sample:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <script>
       function selecting_key(whatKey){
              if(whatKey.keyCode==13){
         whatKey.preventDefault();
        }
       }
      </script>
     <body>
     <form>
    <input type="text"  onkeydown='selecting_key(event);'>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you want to check, try changing the `onkeydown` to `onkeyup` to know which event can prevent the page from being submitted

Comment: Tried it and nothing changes.

Comment: Have you tried inserting  the `e.preventDefault();` part inside your `if` block then try changing the condition to `e.keyCode == 13`?

Comment: Just tried, the same behaviour. For some reason, that piece of code is never executed. Perhaps the request is thrown by another element, but I can't find anything.

Comment: I have edited my answer @vjsp90. I have included a working code regarding on preventing the default behavior of the Enter key

Comment: Thanks,it works., althought I don't know why this does and the previous  solution doesn't do. Is onkeydown called before keydown?

Comment: `onkeydown` and `keydown` is doing the same thing @vjsp90. I dont have an answer on why your previous code is not working before but maybe you can try to declare an event directly inside your HTML element if an event is not working using jQuery and vice versa